# How to add our own sentences and polarities in Vader Sentiment Analysis

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science, sentiment-analysis, vader

I am using vader sentiment analysis to analyze covid 19 related tweets. But in the bi grams and tri grams I have seen that words like " positive covid " , "positive cases", "tested positive", "test positive" are categorized under positive sentiments in Vader Sentiment Analysis. [image]
Here Green Column is positive sentiments, pink column is negative sentiments and yellow column is neutral sentiments